# search 200 k array of arrays of integers?? java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search

I have array containing 200 000 lines of integers ( containing smaller arrays of integers). Each line contains 1 - 20 members. Integer are 0-200 in value. Looks like this:

```
...

[42, 66, 54, 145, 183, 198, 104, 24, 22, 125, 127]
[71, 149, 59, 147, 115, 36, 124]  // <--lets say i am searching for this line
[27, 141, 19, 75, 101, 149, 36, 7, 12, 108, 69, 149, 1, 39, 55, 87, 178, 76, 133]
[94, 170, 185, 17, 121, 42, 51, 70, 176, 187, 31, 181, 167, 200, 144, 126, 123, 120, 91, 40]
[112, 162, 173, 145, 0, 165, 106, 137]
[141, 198, 32]
...
```

How to search for particular line in it? Please direct me to right direction, if possible link me to example.

I mean search - when i type in 71, 149, 59 i would get my line (or close to it if there are several similar lines).
Spend days reading around still not sure how to proceed. Please help. (I have list sorted ascending)

which method is better, hashing? binary search? Any good keyword or link appreciated (first time i am doing search)

Comment: If you've spent days on it can you show your attempts and explain what specifically you're having issues with. As it stands you're asking us to write it for you.

Comment: Also, it's better to establish a rule for returning "the" line. Perhaps a rule that says "I'll return the first line that contains `someString`"; it can be as complex a rule as you wish but don't introduce needless constraints on yourself.

Comment: @Chief I'd be delighted if you write it for me :) But if you point me to right direction will be also good :)

Comment: I don't understand the criteria for finding the line. Must it contain all the numbers you enter? I the same order? Right next to each other?

Comment: in the same order from left to right. But not neccesserly all numbers. so typing 71 would find many lines, typing in 71, 149, 59 would return few lines or only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to optimise your search prematurely. Unless you are going to do it many times a second then an exhaustive search should be fine. I'm assuming by 'close to it' your intention is to find all arrays that start with the values you pass in.

Here is an exhaustive search using Java 8:

```
List<int[]> searchForArrays(int[][] data, int[] value) {
    return Arrays.stream(data).parallel()
        .filter(line -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
                if (i >= line.length || value[i] != line[i])
                    return false;
            return true;
        });
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This finds all arrays that match your search term. If you need to find just one array that matches and your array is sorted then you could speed things up with a binary search:

```
int[] binarySearch(int[][] data, int from, int to, int[] value) {
    int trial = (from + to) / 2;
    if (from >= to)
        return new int[]{};
    int compare = compareTo(data[trial], value);
    if (compare < 0)
        return binarySearch(data, from, trial, value);
    else if (compare > 0)
        return binarySearch(data, trial, to, value);
    else 
        return data[trial];
}
```

If you really need to optimise then you'd be better off reorganising your data into a tree with a map from values to nodes. Then searching would be a trivial matter of following the nodes of the tree for the values you are searching for. This could look something like:

```
class Node {
    private final Map<Integer, Node> children;
    private boolean terminal;
}
```

Comment: exhaustive search. Thanks for keyword and example. Yes, I don't need search many times per second just on button click.

Comment: I ended up using exhaustive search - looping through list from beggining until i find my line seems it's quick enough without optimisations, thanx 4 guidance

Answer (score 1):

How about something like below, I can flesh it out later if it suits:

```
package area51;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Junk {
    Node root;
    static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public Node initialize() {
        root = new Node(0);
        int[][] matrix = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
        for (int[] row : matrix) {
            Node parent = root;
            for (int childValue : row) {
                parent = parent.addChild(childValue);
            }
        }
        return root;
    }

    public List<int[]> find(int[] key, int limit){
        //use some recursion
        List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        Node node = root;
        for (Node child: node.children){
            ....
        }
        return list;
    }


    class Node {
        int value;
        List<Node> children;

        Node(int value) {
            super();
            this.value = value;
        }

        Node addChild(int childValue) {
            if (children == null) {
                children = new ArrayList<Node>();
            }
            Node child = new Node(childValue);
            children.add(child);
            return child;
        }
    }
}
```